# How to fill a list with values from another list

Tags: prolog

I'm just starting to learn about prolog, and I'd like to create a program that helps me do the following:

Given two lists:

```
List1 = [1,2,3,4].
List2 = [_,_,_,_,_,_].
```

I'd like to make sure that the values from List2 are values that exist in List1. In this case, there're many different solutions, such as:

```
List2=[3,1,2,2,1,2]
List2=[4,1,2,3,4,3]
List2=[2,4,2,4,1,2]
List2=[1,3,2,1,3,4]
...
```

However, I don't know how to do this in Prolog. So far, I've tried the following:

```
domain([x,y,w,z]).
solution([_,_,_,_,_,_]).

fillList(B):-
    domain(A),
    solution(B),
    member(X, A),
    member(X, B).

result: B = [x, _, _, _, _, _] .

It only adds one value.
```

Then I tried this:

```
fillList(B):-
   domain(A),
   solution(B),
   foreach(member(X,B),member(X, A)).

result: B = [_, _, _, _, _, _]
```

It doesn't add any value.

Clarification: List2 is meant to have more elements than List1, so certain values can be duplicated.

Comment: Are you intending that List2 can have *duplicate* values in it, e.g. `[1,2,3,4,1,2]`?

Comment: Yes, the only restriction is that the each value has to be a member of List1.

Answer (score 2):

From the example given, it seems you are accepting duplicates.

```
:- use_module(library(lambda)).

all_from(Xs, Es) :-
    maplist(Es+\E^member(E,Es), Xs).


?- List2 = [_,_,_,_], all_from(List2, [1,2,3,4]).
   List2 = [1,1,1,1]
;  List2 = [1,1,1,2]
;  List2 = [1,1,1,3]
;  List2 = [1,1,1,4]
;  List2 = [1,1,2,1]
;  ...
;  List2 = [1,3,2,1]
;  ...
;  List2 = [2,4,2,4]
;  ...
;  List2 = [3,1,2,2]
;  ...
;  List2 = [4,1,2,3]
;  ... .
```

Same without `library(lambda)`:

```
list_member(Es, E) :-
    member(E, Es).

all_from2(Xs, Es) :-
    maplist(list_member(Es), Xs).
```

Same without `maplist/2`:

```
all_from3([], _).
all_from3([X|Xs], Es) :-
   member(X, Es),
   all_from3(Xs, Es).
```

Answer (score 0):

Can simply use [permutation](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=permutation/2):

```
has_members(L1, L2) :-
    permutation(L1, L2).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(findall(L, has_members([1,2,3,4], L), Ls)).
% 212 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (99% CPU, 10873468 Lips)
Ls = [[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,3],[1,3,2,4],[1,3,4,2],[1,4,2,3],[1,4,3,2],[2,1,3,4],[2,1,4,3],[2,3,1,4],[2,3,4,1],[2,4,1,3],[2,4,3,1],[3,1,2,4],[3,1,4,2],[3,2,1,4],[3,2,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[3,4,2,1],[4,1,2,3],[4,1,3,2],[4,2,1,3],[4,2,3,1],[4,3,1,2],[4,3,2,1]].
```

Or, to include duplicates and with a flexible length:

```
has_members([], _).
has_members([H|T], Seeds) :-
    nth1(_, Seeds, H),
    has_members(T, Seeds).
```

Can use `member(H, Seeds)` instead of `nth1(_, Seeds, H)`, so this is essentially identical to @false's `all_from3`

Result:

```
?- length(L, _), has_members(L, [1,2,3,4]).
L = [] ;
L = [1] ;
L = [2] ;
L = [3] ;
L = [4] ;
L = [1,1] ;
L = [1,2] ;
...

?- length(L, 6), has_members(L, [1,2,3,4]).
L = [1,1,1,1,1,1] ;
L = [1,1,1,1,1,2] ;
L = [1,1,1,1,1,3] ;
L = [1,1,1,1,1,4] ;
L = [1,1,1,1,2,1] ;
...
```

Comment: Does not find `List2=[3,1,2,2]`.

Answer (score 0):

It's best to start simple. To go through a list (without the library's sometimes-hard-to-use shortcuts, which I'd put off for now), use recursion, as in

```
f([]).               /* Base case -- empty list */
f([First|Rest]) :-   /* Recursive step          */
      /* set up First correctly, and then */,
      f(Rest).
```

In this case, we want First to be a `member` of the domain. So this works:

```
fillList(Solution) :-
   domain(Domain),
   solution(Solution),
   fillList(Solution,Domain).

fillList([],_).
fillList([First|Rest],Domain) :-
   member(First,Domain),
   fillList(Rest,Domain).
```

Two predicates with the same name? No problem, if they have different numbers of arguments. Do we really need two predicates? Given this setup, yes: one gets info from domain/1 and solution/1, and the other goes thru the Solution list recursively so it handles each element.